# Add function on AppEngine Memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

Im using memcache to store a json, and it's working. But the problem is that the cache size grow if I call that line above many times:

```
memcache.Client.add(memcache.Client(),"searchindex",json)
```

So I looked at the memcache viewer and the content still the same, since Im using a key that's already on cache. But, even though the size of cache continues to increase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, that's a really odd way to invoke an instance method. Normally you would do this:

```
memcache.Client().add("searchindex", json)
```

Or simply:

```
memcache.add("searchindex", json)
```

Since `add` will not overwrite a key that already exists in cache, calling it repeatedly should have no impact on the behavior of your application.

Whether or not these calls increase the cache size shouldn't really be a concern. Memcache is designed to make memory available as it's needed by your application, based on a least use algorithm. Junk memory from inert should `add` calls should certainly be evicted first.

Comment: I was concerned about the increase of memcache size because I'm charged for that on appengine.There's no way that I can avoid that waste of space?

Comment: In what sense are you charged for memory? You're charged for instance hours, and instances have a fixed amount of memory. If you run out of memory, memcache should start evicting stale data and yielding memory back to your application. I fail to see how this would ever cause you to be charged more.

Comment: You are not charged for memcache.

Comment: I know this was written three years ago, but now days you're charged for memcache - $0.06 per GB/hour. https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs

Comment: No, as far as I can read, the default "shared memcache" is free, while the "dedicated memcache" is billed the $0.06/GB/hour.